# How do I fix these broken dependencies?

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude

aptitude tells me I have some packages with broken dependencies:

```
kmiller@debian-dev-box:~$ sudo aptitude search '.*' | grep ^.B
iB  console-setup-linux             - Linux specific part of console-setup      
iB  gir1.2-freedesktop              - Introspection data for some FreeDesktop co
iB  gir1.2-glib-2.0                 - Introspection data for GLib, GObject, Gio 
iB  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10           - Description: GObject introspection data fo
iB  gir1.2-json-1.0                 - GLib JSON manipulation library (introspect
iBA libatk-adaptor                  - AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge                   
iB  libgcc1                         - GCC support library                       
iBA libgfortran3                    - Runtime library for GNU Fortran applicatio
iBA libgomp1                        - GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library         
iB  libstdc++6                      - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

But the 'broken'-ness can't be too bad because:

```
kmiller@debian-dev-box:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

kmiller@debian-dev-box:~$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It's most worrying that libgcc1 has broken dependencies.

What do I do to find out what to fix?!

```
kmiller@debian-dev-box:~$ sudo aptitude install -f
...
0 packages upgraded, 11 newly installed, 177 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: gcc-4.3 (< 4.3.6-1) but 4.3.5-4 is to be installed.
 gir1.2-json-1.0 : Conflicts: gir1.0-json-glib-1.0 but 0.10.2-2squeeze1 is to be installed.
 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 : Conflicts: gir1.0-gstreamer-0.10 but 0.10.30-1 is to be installed.
 libgfortran3 : Breaks: gcc-4.3 (< 4.3.6-1) but 4.3.5-4 is to be installed.
 libgomp1 : Breaks: gcc-4.3 (< 4.3.6-1) but 4.3.5-4 is to be installed.
 libgcc1 : Breaks: gcc-4.3 (< 4.3.6-1) but 4.3.5-4 is to be installed.
 gir1.2-freedesktop : Conflicts: gir1.0-freedesktop but 0.6.14-1+b1 is to be installed.
 gir1.2-glib-2.0 : Conflicts: gir1.0-glib-2.0 but 0.6.14-1+b1 is to be installed.
 libatk-adaptor : Conflicts: at-spi but 1.32.0-2 is to be installed.
 console-setup-linux : Breaks: console-terminus but 4.30-2 is to be installed.
```

Comment: What about `aptitude install -f`?

Comment: Hmm good one....aptitude wants to uninstall 177 packages but it does give me some more info

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`apt-get` and `aptitude` have different dependency resolvers. You can get aptitude to offer suggestions for fixing the broken packages with `aptitude install -f`. Judging by your updated question, it look like you have mixed releases or distros in your `sources.list`.

Comment: Aptitude is great at fixing things for Single distribution systems. Aptitude is practically useless if you add 2 distributions (Vivid and Trusty in my case) to apt/sources.list (so I could cherry pick some new versions). Same problems as KarlM.

Good to know im not the only one.